# Loop through multiple arrays php

Tags: php

Can anybody explain me how can i get the value of 'ubicacion' in those arrays, and then, store that value in a php variable.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [PC] => Array
            (
                [ubicacion] => 02021002
            )

      )

 )
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [PC] => Array
            (
                [ubicacion] => 034267211
            )

      )

 )
```

Comment: You don't need a loop. `echo $array[0]['PC']['ubicacion']` will give you the required value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm just begining to learn php, one last question. What if i want to get the values of ubicacion simultaneously. with those arrays. Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PC] => Array
                (
                    [ubicacion] => 02021002
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PC] => Array
                (
                    [ubicacion] => 01001002
                )

        )

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the value of it..

```
$value = $array[0]['PC']['ubicacion'];
```